# How to create "multipleOf" constraint in MySQL CREATE TABLE statement?

Tags: mysql

Desired Output: A database field that stores INT values in multiples of 5 only

I am trying to create a MySQL table with "multipleOf" constraint. I have tried doing it using CONSTRAINT and CHECK like:

```
CONSTRAINT multipleOf CHECK(fooUnit%5==0)
```

This is what my CREATE TABLE statement looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
fooID INT NOT NULL,
fooUnit INT,
CONSTRAINT multipleOf CHECK(fooUnit%5==0),
PRIMARY KEY(fooID)
);
```

Comment: You could build this into the INSERT logic

Comment: There 2 errors one is using keyword multipleOf as name for constraint and second it should be =.  not ==

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
fooID INT NOT NULL,
fooUnit INT,
CONSTRAINT multipleOff CHECK(fooUnit%5=0),
PRIMARY KEY(fooID)
);
```